# PHP implode explode comma separated values for use in if else statement

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I am working on a project where I need to enter comma separated values in a database field and then extract the data to use in if and else statement.

For example: in the database field `user_status` i have usernames like `admin,admin1,admin2,admin3........etc`. I want to use these values like:

```
$user_status = $row['user_status']; // database values of all the usernames
$username    = $_SESSION['username']; // username of the logged in user eg. admin

if($user_status == $username) // if session username matches with a username in the database field
{
  statements;
}else{
  statements;
}
```

I want to extract the comma separated database values from the database and match if the logged in user's username matches with one of many username's in the database. But I am not pretty sure how to do this. Please help me experts.

Comment: Take a look at php functions `explode` and `in_array`

Comment: Is this question significantly different from your other question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33651972/php-explode-data-to-be-used-in-where-clause ?

Comment: yes.. its completely different... its both contains question on implode explode but the query is completely different..

Answer (score 1):

Create an array with `explode` and use `in_array` to check if the `$username` exists in the `$user_status` array.

```
<?php
$username    = $_SESSION['username'];
$user_status = explode(',', $row['user_status']);

if (in_array($username, $user_status)) {
    //...
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: when I echo $user_status = explode(',', $uhs['pads_status']); it returns
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\sites\ptc\member_ads.php on line 87
Array

Comment: You don't need to echo the variable assignment, just echo the function result, just use echo explode.....

Comment: @LaptopMedico Why would you echo the `$user_status`? What do you try to achieve? `$user_status` is an array, so you have to use `print_r` or `var_dump` to debug. Maybe you should update you question or better create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution you can search for the string encapsulated in comas

```
if (strpos($user_status, ','.$username.',') !== false) 
   echo 'user found';
else 
    echo 'not found';
```